# Build/Publish angular 5 and ASP.NET Core 2.0 Application

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, deployment, publish, ng-build

As ASP.NET Core and Angular are latest technologies so i build my management application using them now i need to deploy it on windows shared hosting and i am getting lot of issues, i don't need solution to those issues.But if any one can provide me some step by step article/guide link to deploy Application **(ASP.NET Core 2.0 + Angular 5)** to Windows shared hosting of  [A2 Hosting](https://www.a2hosting.com/).
Thank you!
P.S: once i got the solution up votes and **tick mark** is sure.

Comment: Mostly people uploaded solutions for IIS and Azure deployment.

Comment: There is a [link](https://www.a2hosting.co.uk/kb/a2-hosting-products/windows-hosting/publish-a-site-from-visual-studio-using-ftps) on the A2 Hosting site that shows you how to publish via FTPS. Have you tried that already?

Comment: @SimplyGed yes, i visited that link that's not sufficient. Actually i know how to publish i think the problems are coming when i build the angular part of application. People say i cant publish ASP.NET Core  and Angular at one place.

Comment: Did you figure out how to publish a .Net Core web app to A2?

Comment: no i didn't, due to dead line i converted the app to MVC 5

Comment: As per my knowledge no hosting provide provides .net core support in windows hosting server.